# GridPanel as item of tabPanel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, tabpanel, gridpanel

I'm having trouble knowing if I syntactically have this setup right. From another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424785/grid-inside-tab), I understand to add the GridPanel to the tabBar items, which I do so below. In my App.js, I define a grid copied from the ExtJS example ([here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.Component)).

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    // Details can be seen at
    // http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.Component?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel
});
```

Below that, I create an instance of my app:

```
appname.App = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {

fullscreen: true,

tabBar: {
    ui: 'gray',
    dock: 'bottom',
    layout: { pack: 'center' }
},

cardSwitchAnimation: false,

initComponent: function() {

    if (navigator.onLine) {

        // Add items to the tabPanel
        this.items = [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            iconCls: 'tab1',
            xtype: 'tab1',
            pages: this.accountPages
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            iconCls: 'tab2',
            xtype: 'tab2',
            pages: this.accountPages
        },
        grid];
    } else {
        this.on('render', function(){
            this.el.mask('No internet connection.');
        }, this);
    }

    appname.App.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}

});
```

The app normally loads just fine, but with the addition of `grid`, it breaks and nothing loads.

Syntactically, should I be defining grid inside the app instantiation like A) `grid: ...`, B) `this.grid = new ...`, or C) as I have it as a regular `var` named `grid`?

Many thanks.

Comment: at a high level, nothing seems wrong with your approach. are the two snippets in the same js file?

Comment: They are, in fact. I'd ideally refactor. I just wanted to test implementing the grid as a tab item.

Comment: Are you getting an errors in your error console?  Can you verify that the grid panel is actually being created?

Comment: Is it a Sencha Touch application or ExtJS one?

Comment: @Swar: It's Sencha Touch (I'll fix tags). @joekrell: Good call. I'll see if it's actually being instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt GridPanel comes with Sencha Touch. So, that Ext.grid.GridPanel will not work here. However, you can use Simoen's TouchGrid extension from [here](http://www.simoens.org/Sencha-Projects/demos/).

All the source codes are available [here](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens).